# Looking for a picture of Fixer's sandsurfer hover device

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

According to Star Wars Legends, in *Galaxy Guide 5: Return of the Jedi*, Second Edition 1995, Luke Skywalker tells to Voren Na'al a tale about his friend Laze "Fixer" Loneozner, a skilled mechanic from Tatooine, who invented a sport called "sandsurfing." In the sport, a person would wear repulsor discs on their feet and grab on to a set of handles that connected to a sand skiff by a thin cord. As the skiff moved along, the "surfer" would perform all manners of flips and tricks on the countless sloping dunes and unobstructed sand of the Dune Sea. The skiff might be set to drive itself in autopilot mode.

I've been looking for an image of Fixer's original sandsurfer device without success. So far, the closest thing I've found is the *Deluxe Luke Skywalker's desert sport skiff* produced by Kenner, but it's not designed after the one described in Legends.

[image: image of Deluxe Luke Skywalker's desert sport skiff]

I also did some research, including *Star Wars: The Movie Trilogy Sourcebook*, but the sandsurfing device is only described in words.

I wonder if there is a Star Wars behind the scenes still image or a picture of the aforementioned sandsurfer hover device used in Fixer's sport.

I'm not a cartoonist but I have extemporized with a draft of what I imagine could be, more or less, Fixer's sandsurfer.

[image: My drawing idea of Fixer's sandsurfer]

Comment: It's prose only, and from a single source; https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sandsurfing

Comment: and it was created in 1995, well after actual film production, so no behind the scenes images. It was purely an RPG invention